# Background Video is not working in Mobile for banner

Tags: jquery

I have used Jquery Plugin covervid.min.js to add background video on banner,it is working on Desktop,but video is not Playing in mobile view.

```html
<div class=bgvideo>
  <div class="masthead">
    <video class="masthead-video" preload autoplay loop muted poster="images/banner/paragliding.jpg">
      <source src="images/aeros.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="masthead-overlay"></div>
    <div class=owl_text>
      <div class=owl-carousel>
        <div class=text1>
          <h1>Explore the Exciting Landmarks of Malaysia</h1>
          <p>Choose the Best Suitable for You &amp; Your Family </p>
        </div>
        <div class=text2>
          <h1>Venture into the Land of Islands, Sea, and Incredible Countryside</h1>
          <p>Attractive and Exciting Rides at Affordable Price</p>
        </div>
        <div class=text3>
          <h1>A True Adventure Paradise</h1>
          <p>Lifetime Memory Flying Over the Natural Heritage</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
coverVid(document.querySelector('.masthead-video'), 640, 360);
```

```css
.masthead {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-image: none;
}

.masthead-video {
  z-index: 0;
}

.masthead-overlay {
  background-color: #0000002e;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I also tried youtube jquery plugins (jquery.youtubebackground.js), still it's not working in mobile view. Please help me to fix this error. 
Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: I assume you are referring to "autoplay" of videos on mobile, if so, "autoplay" on mobile won't work like on a computer, it's kind of disabled, some restrictions were lifted on a android & ios that allows you to autoplay a video that doesn't have any sound or it is started with an option like { mute: true }.

Comment: I already added mute attribute in code: <video class="masthead-video" preload autoplay loop muted poster="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/images/banner/paragliding.jpg">
   <source src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/images/aeros.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>